# Look ups Exceeds the Limit Set by Admin

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a list where I need to provide 18 People pickers. When you try to look at the view it says this exceeds the limit set by the Admin. This is an off-prem solution and Microsoft has control of this number not me. In the end I really just need to be able to input and display the names on a form. My thoughts were to create two lists and use an InfoPath form to display the data. I am having trouble getting this to work. Any thoughts on how I might accomplish the end goal?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't need 18 different columns, just the capability to store 18 names you should be able to set a single column to allow multiple names (or a couple of different columns to allow multiple names).

If you go to List settings, People Picker Column settings there should be an option to allow multiple selections. From there the end user should be able to add 18  people to that single field.

(The above is based on 2013 on-prem, but should be the same for 365).